# Does android supports video call?

Tags: android

we are searching for months but there is no satisfied article found to this question.
we need to make video call in Android App without using any Third Party SDK

Comment: Not familiar with the topic, but looks like you could use WebRTC: [Can I implement a video chat in an app without any third party SDK?](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-implement-a-video-chat-in-an-app-without-any-third-party-SDK) and [Real time video communication functionality in android without 3rd party services](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/342745/real-time-video-communication-functionality-in-android-without-3rd-party-service). (I just searched for _"make video call in Android App without using any Third Party SDK"_ and found those immediately.)

Comment: Also: [best way to implement Video calling in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330091/best-way-to-implement-video-calling-in-android-application)

Comment: Ok will overview these links. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You should search for **Session Initiation Protocol** in android (SIP)
here is a quick start

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip

Comment: Thanks for this link. Will overview this.